# How to check if user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a command that sends a DM to user and the user is defined like this:

```js
    let user;
    if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
      user = message.mentions.users.first();
    } else if (args[0]) {
      user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]).user;
    }
```

But if I ping a user that is not in this server or write something that is not `@user`, it sends an error "user is not defined". I tried making `if (user == "undefined")`, but it just aborts before it reaches it or if I put it above it can't work.

Comment: Remove the quotes from undefined. `if (user === undefined)`

Comment: I tried, but the problem is it gives me the error here: user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]).user; so i doesn't reach the if statement

Comment: Just replace this `if (message.mentions.users?.first())` because when a parsed Message cant find a proper mention because no active user is found, users are undefined

Comment: @TinoZ I don't understand what to replace and with what I tried adding the ? to the if statement, but it gives me SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for the members with `message.guild.members` and then get the user from there, you could get the [`client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) and check if a user with the `args[0]` ID exists. If it doesn't exist, you can simply check `if (!user)` you don't have to check if it's `undefined`.

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.client.users.cache.get(args[0]);

if (!user) 
  return message.channel.send('There is no user mentioned');

message.channel.send(`You mentioned ${user}`);
```

You can also use `fetch()` to get the user instead of relying on `cache`:

```js
let user;

try {
  user = message.mentions.users.first() || (await message.client.users.fetch(args[0]));
} catch (error) { console.log(error); }

if (!user) 
  return message.channel.send('There is no user mentioned');

message.channel.send(`You mentioned ${user}`);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, and if I may ask which method would you recommend using?

Comment: When I ran it the method that is not relying on cache it sent the message There is no user mentioned and gave me this error:
`DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
user_id: Value "<@!670320674266546186>" is not snowflake.`

Comment: What was the value of `args[0]`? The snowflake (`670320674266546186`) or this string `"<@!670320674266546186>"`? `args[0]` should be a snowflake.

Comment: The value of args[0] was @user, which is basically <@!userid>, you can try adding a \ before a ping and sending the message.

Comment: but if i try sending with the Id it works perfectly fine!

Comment: and using the first method I don't get the error, so I'll stick to it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For each variable in javascript you can take its type and obviously if its type is `=== 'undefined'` then it is undefined.

```
if(typeof comment === 'undefined') {
    alert('Variable "comment" is undefined.');
}
```

Comment: I tried, but the problem is it gives me the error here: user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]).user; so i doesn't reach the if statement

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking if you have written user as `"undefined"` when actually you want to see if the user is `undefined`.
Another issue with your code is that `args[0]` will return the command name when you want the next argument over from that, `args[1]`.
Full example:

```js
let user;
if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
    user = message.mentions.users.first();
} else if (args[0]) {
    user = message.guild.members.fetch(args[1]).user;
} else {
    return message.channel.send("Please provide a user"); //Sends if the message author did not provide a user
}

if (user == undefined) return message.chanel.send("I could not find the user you are looking for"); //Sends if the user is not in the current guild or doesn't exist
```

Comment: it gives the error before it reaches the if statement

Comment: user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]).user; here

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take another look.

Comment: Even after doing as you said it still gives the error:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: @newbie It sounds like the error is not coming from the code you have provided us.